How do I replace detail view controller navigation stack when presenting
I'm working with a UISplitViewController that's using some storyboards but now moving to programmatic presentation (which is what I'm familiar with). I have a VC that's currently presenting as a push, but I'm trying to move out to presenting as a detail view on a split view controller.
The problem is that it's presented correctly in the detail side, but the back button unravels to the most previous detail view controller. This messes up the navigation, especially when in the collapsed view.
How can I present the detail view controller as the only VC on the detail stack? The rest of the app detail view controllers behave as though they are replacing the detail view controller stack.
I'm currently trying:
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:vc sender:self];

